# How do I call a function on button click to listen for another mouse click in React Hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, addeventlistener, use-effect

I am using React Hooks and I want to do something like this: I have a button, when clicked, I want it to listen for another mouse click, but I have read that I should not call the addEventListener in a function.

I tried with addEventListener in useEffect but failed. I want the event listener to only trigger when the button was clicked, but useEffect will always run before that. I have no idea what to do.

```
useEffect(() = > {
    document.addEventListener("click", mouseClickHandler)

    return () => {
        document.removeEventListener("click", mouseClickHandler) 
    }
})

const buttonClickHandler = () => {
    // ?? has to do something here to trigger the addEventListener

}

const mouseClickHandler = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target); // and do other stuff
}

return(
    <button onClick={buttonClickHandler} />
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a state variable that tracks whether the button was clicked, and then have useEffect react to that to add your listener:

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

const [didClickButton, setDidClickButton] = useState(false)

useEffect(() => {
  if (didClickButton) {
    document.addEventListener("click", mouseClickHandler)
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("click", mouseClickHandler)
    }
  } else {
    document.removeEventListener("click", mouseClickHandler)
  }
}, [didClickButton])

const buttonClickHandler = () => {
  setDidClickButton(true)
}

const mouseClickHandler = (event) => {
  console.log(event.target)
  setDidClickButton(false) // If you want to reset the behavior again
}

return(
    <button onClick={buttonClickHandler} />
)
```

This is completely untested as I'm sitting at a bar drinking Campari, so you may need to tweak it slightly. But this is the general idea.

Comment: It works! Thanks, I knew that it would be an if statement inside useEffect but it took a few hours and I still couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

You can set a state when the button is clicked and set a state to it.

Later, use the same state in a `useEffect` so as to add and remove the `click` listeners on the document. This way your hooks can be reused or extracted to a custom hook. Even if another button needs to trigger the same behavior, you can use same setup.

```
const [listenDocument, setListenDocument] = useState(false);
useEffect(() = > {
    const mouseClickHandler = (event) => {
      console.log(event.target); // and do other stuff
      // I'm guessing you would set listenDocument to false here.
    }

    if(listenDocument) {
      document.addEventListener("click", mouseClickHandler);
    }

    return () => {
        document.removeEventListener("click", mouseClickHandler) 
    }
}, [listenDocument])

const buttonClickHandler = () => {
    setListenDocument(true);
}

return(
    <button onClick={buttonClickHandler} />
)
```

And you can add event listeners to `document`, can't add a `ref` to document anyway.

Comment: Thanks, this one works too when setting the state to false in the mouseClickHandler